# Custom Camera Implemetation

Tags: android, camera

Implemented custom camera using  `extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`.It works fine in some devices ,but in some devices getting exception like Caused by:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1391)
```

Even given all permissions in manifest file.what is the issue,can anyone give me some suggestions.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the logging statements immediately preceding your stack trace. Sometimes there is information there that can be useful. However, in general, there are any number of possible "issues" here, and so without the source code that is triggering this and without knowing what "some devices" are, nobody will be able to help you very much.

Comment: That link lists every possible gist. Please link to *your gist*.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i used https://codeload.github.com/dawidgatti/dgCam/zip/master

Answer (score 1):

That's normal if your are trying to fix width and height to camera parameters like this :

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

You should `getParameters` :

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
```

To retrieve Size that can be used with the device camera (its an Array normally) and then apply the good Size to `setParameters`.